# Regex and Yahoo Pipes: How to replace end of url

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, pipe, yahoo-pipes

Here's the Pipe though you may not need it to answer the question: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=85a288a1517e615b765df9603fd604bd

I am trying to modify all url's as so:

```
http://mediadownloads.mlb.com/mlbam/2009/08/12/mlbf_6073553_th_3.jpg with
http://mediadownloads.mlb.com/mlbam/2009/08/12/mlbtv_6073553_1m.mp4
```

The syntax should be something like:

In item.mediaUrl replace f with tv and In item.mediaUrl replace last 8 characters with 1m.mp4

```
mlbf_(\d+)_.* replaced w/ mlbtv_$1_1m.mp4
```

breaks the rss feed though I know I am close

Any idea as to what syntax I need there?

Comment: That regex works,  Testing in Firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex and replacement look okay to me, assuming the regex is being applied *only* to the URLs.  If it were being applied to the surrounding text as well, the `.*` would tend to consume a lot more than you wanted.  See what happens if you change the regex to this:

```
mlbf_(\d+)_[\w.]+
```

Comment: The regex works, but you're right, he could be replacing past the end of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how this yahoo pipes work, but this regex should do it according this [site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html):

Regex:

```
.*?/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/mlbf_([0-9]*)_.*
```

Substitution:

```
http://mediadownloads.mlb.com/mlbam/$1/$2/$3/mlbtv_$4_1m.mp4
```